# how to color share price changes: using css() method on dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set the css color property of 38 dynamically created span elements that are populated with API JSON response data (live stock exchange).

Each span element with .change contains a numerical value that indicates share price changes.
Each of these change indicators should have a certain color conditional on its value, as we are used to. Meaning, *if value < 0 it should appear red, if value > 0 it should appear green, and if value = 0 no action should be taken.*

In my jQuery script the API request works fine and I have included it as relevant context only. **My issue** is the subsequent coloring of the .change elements' inner html which should actually be colored according to the rules outlined above.

I guess the css() method isn't working correctly because the JSON data is being pulled into the document after the page DOM is ready. In this case implementing a proper callback should do the job, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any advice on this or other approaches to solving the coloring issue would be very helpful!

Please see my code below. I'm thankful for any advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type='text/css'>

#magic-line {font-size: 90%;}
#gse-primer {padding: 0; text-align: center;}
#gse-wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
.stocks {display: inline-block; width: 120px; text-align: center;}
#gse {animation-name: slide; animation-duration: 90s; animation-iteration-   count: infinite; animation-timing-function: linear; white-space: nowrap;}
@keyframes slide {from {margin-left: 0px;} to {margin-left: -4560px;}}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='magic-line' class='col-xs-12'>      
<div id='gse-primer' class='hidden-xs col-sm-2'>Share Price:<br>Vol. Traded</div>
<div id='gse-wrapper' class='col-sm-10'><span id='gse'></span></div>
</div>     

<!-- jQuery Google CDN -->
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

// API request for stock data

$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("http://dev.kwayisi.org/apis/gse/live?callback=?", function(data)   {
console.log(data);
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
$("#gse").append("<div class='stocks'>" + " " + "<b>" + value.name + "</b>" + " " + value.price + " " + "<span class='change'>" + value.change + "</span>" + "<br>" + value.volume + "</div>");
});     
});
}); 

// adding color to indicate changes in share prices

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.change').each(function(i, obj) {
if ($(this).val() < 0) { $(this).css('color','#E60000'); }
else if ($(this).val() > 0) { $(this).css('color','#32cd32'); }
else { };
});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you print the value add an attribute in the `span` element

```
<span class='change' data-change='" + value.change + "'>" + value.change + "</span>
```

thus use an attribute selector in `CSS` to properly style the element

```
[data-change]      { /* color for positive values */ }
[data-change="0"]  { /* color for zero value */      }
[data-change^="-"] { /* color for negative values */ }
```

> [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyrggR)

doing so you will keep off the style part from the javascript part and you will avoid useless and expensive calls to the jQuery library (and this is good both for mantainance and performance)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am currently not able to check whether it is working for me because the API response does'nt even include a single price change...will get back to you once I've checked.

Comment: anyway @YogeshSharma is right, the value of a span element can be retrieved by text() method, not val()

Answer (score 1):

I don't think in case of span tag you will get any value by .val() function. you need to use .text() function and then convert value in Integer. Please use below code and check if it works for you -

// adding color to indicate changes in share prices

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.change').each(function() {

if(parseInt($(this).text()) < 0) { $(this).css('color','#E60000'); }
else if(parseInt($(this).text()) > 0) { $(this).css('color','#32cd32'); }

});
  },2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will check and respond once the API response contains price changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this below css for custom colors**

You can also test for all possible values by changing class colors in below code.

```
.posClass {color : green;}
.negClass {color : red;}
.zerClass {color : black;}
```

**Replace this jquery code where it has all 3 conditions which you have asked.**

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.change').each(function() {
    var valChange   = $(this).text();
    var valClass    = "negClass";
        if(valChange == 0){
            valClass = "zerClass";
        }
        else if(valChange > 0){
            valClass = "posClass";
        }
    $(this).addClass(valClass);
    });
},1000);
```

Comment: yes no problem i have came up with solution use above edited code which may help you for the same.